# Event handler return value to form

Tags: c#

I am making a voice recognition software that contain a Class named `voice`. Now in the form there are a button and a textbox. When pressing the button it will make an instance from `voice` class and call the method `Loadspeech()`. My main issue is when run the program, enable voice recognition and speech, the system will go to this method:

```
void sRE_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
```

and that's great.

However, I want to pass speech value from class event handler `sRE_SpeechRecognized` to the `textbox` in the form every time I speech.

```
class Voice
{
    public string speech ="";
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sRE = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    public void loadSpeech()
    {
        sRE.SpeechRecognized += sRE_SpeechRecognized;
        sRE.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        sRE.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        try { sRE.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }

    void sRE_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        speech = e.Result.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a class for this?
Just create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine in your MainForm and use your code.

```
 void sRE_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = e.Result.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah. You are right i already have that. but what if I need to call this from several forms. then I will keep repeating the same code again and again.

Comment: Then you should make your SpeechRecognitonEngine public and static, like this:`code`public static SpeechRecognitionEngine sRE = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(); Then you should find in your other form MainWindow.sRE.

Comment: what about transfer e.Result.Text in Voice class to textbox1.Text in Form everytime I speech.

Comment: If you're using your Voice class, you have to create an eventhandler for the string speech, when its value has changed. But if you just using the the class SpeechRecognitionEngine you don't have do this. Just use your textbox instead of the string, just as I posted it. It's more simple.